# how to access/print a list of a list?

Tags: list

Given;

```
(setq whole '(group1 group2(element1 element2(suba subb subc)         
   element3) group3))
```

I would to print some list of that list, like element2 sublist.

How can i do it?

Comment: See `C-h f elt` to access list elements.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "print."  (Also, could you please format your code according to lisp conventions?)

Comment: something like; (print whole(group2)), displaying the elements of that

Comment: What i want is to access directly to an element or subelement of a list.  So if evaluate (member 'group2 whole) i get all the elements of group2. The question is how to read directly the values (list) of a list of a list. Ie; reading the element2 list from group2 from whole...

Comment: How are "the elements of group2" distinguished? As opposed to, say, the elements of group1 or group3. I can't see any clear structure to your form, other than perhaps *if item X is followed by item Y, and item Y is also a list, then Y is the "elements of X", otherwise Y is just a sibling of X"* -- which you could work with, but isn't very pretty.

Comment: I found a function (author varjag) that does the walking-tree needed to find atoms into sublists; http://paste.lisp.org/display/316306. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Emacs StackExchange site!

**List Structure Clarification**

I suspect you made an error in notating your lisp object.  It looks like you were maybe trying to add an identifier to the second group? Check out [alists and plists](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlistVsPlist) for helpful list structures with keys.  They may be correspond to the object you had in mind.

Maybe this will help clarify things.  Your list object:

```
'(group1 group2(element1 element2(suba subb subc) element3) group3)
```

Should, at a minim, have spaces to make it clear that it is indeed lisp code (and not a mutant child of Scheme and JavaScript):

```
'(group1 group2 (element1 element2 (suba subb subc) element3) group3)
```

In an expanded form for readability (with newlines and indentation) expresses exactly the same structure which may not be what you intended:

***(Preserving the symbol names in the original post; 'group1' 'group2'    are misnomers)***

```
'(
   group1 ; first element of the list (accessed by (elt whole 0) since lists are indexed from zero)
   group2 ; second element (another way of accessing is (nth 1 whole) which is functionally the same as (elt whole 1)
   ( ; third element - is the list you were talking about accessing
     element1 ; first element of your nested list
     element2 ; second element of your nested list
     ( ; third element of the third element
       suba ; first element of the third element of the third element
       subb
       subc
       )
     element3
     )
   group3 ; fourth element of the top-level list
   )
```

**Accessing lists**

In addition to `elt` and `nth` you should also look at using `car` and `cdr`.  Once you understand these and their many variations you should have a strong grasp of how lists work in lisp.

```
(car whole) ; evaluates to the 'group1 symbol you have
(cdr whole) ; evaluates to the rest of the list after 'group1
(cadr whole) ; evaluates to the 'group2 symbol you have
(cddr whole) ; evaluates to the 'group2 symbol you have
```

**Printing**

For printing elements of uncertain type you might want to consider using `prin1`.

Comment: Thank you ebpa for your detailed explanation and clarification. Morever, in addition to elt and nth, there's a way to access a nested element by name instead of index number? ie; (traverse 'suba whole) ?

Comment: @Steve If you are using alists you would use `(cdr (assq 'suba whole))` to get the value if you have used the key `'suba` to store the value (ex: `(setq whole '((suba . "My value")))`).  Note that lists don't inherently represent an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array data structure.  alists only have 'keys' or 'names' because they follow a common convention of storing the key as the car of each cons element.